# Add and remove classes when click on multiple divs using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to style a menu I built and I add a different class on each div element every time someone clicks on them. How can I remove the already added class from this element when I click anyone of the other 3 divs?

```js
$('.fashion-btn').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("active-btn-red");
});

$('.garden-btn').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("active-btn-pink");
});

$('.technology-btn').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("active-btn-purple");
});

$('.auto-btn').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("active-btn-deep-purple");
});
```

```css
.categories-sidebar-popup-menu-row {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 28px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: -0.5px;
  color: #555B66;
}

.active-btn-red {
  background: #E53935;
  color: #fff!important;
}

.active-btn-pink {
  background: #D81B60;
  color: #fff!important;
}

.active-btn-purple {
  background: #8E24AA;
  color: #fff!important;
}

.active-btn-deep-purple {
  background: #5E35B1;
  color: #fff!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="categories-sidebar-popup-menu-row fashion-btn">FASHION</div>
<div class="categories-sidebar-popup-menu-row garden-btn">GARDEN</div>
<div class="categories-sidebar-popup-menu-row technology-btn">TECHNOLOGY</div>
<div class="categories-sidebar-popup-menu-row auto-btn">AUTO</div>
```

I know that i could do something like that for each one of them:

```
$('.fashion-btn').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("active-btn-red");
  $('.garden-btn').removeClass("active-btn-pink");
  $('.technology-btn').removeClass("active-btn-purple");
  $('.auto-btn').removeClass("active-btn-deep-purple");
});
```

But as I will add more than 20 elements in my menu, I would like to ask if there any smarter/shorter way to make this work.

Comment: You might want to consider reformatting your CSS classes to make your jQuery a little easier to write. I would simply add an `active` class to the div. And then instead of `active-btn-color` do, e.g. `.fashion-btn.active { styles }`. This will be a little easier to maintain in the jQuery.

Comment: I would do this in plain javascript, using a single eventhandler that set the class to active on the clicked button and then removed the active class from all other button. But I know, [not enough jquery](https://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @disinfor said in the comments, you could do something like this:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="categories-sidebar-popup-menu-row fashion-btn" data-active-class ='active-btn-red '>FASHION</div>
<div class="categories-sidebar-popup-menu-row garden-btn">GARDEN</div>
<div class="categories-sidebar-popup-menu-row technology-btn">TECHNOLOGY</div>
<div class="categories-sidebar-popup-menu-row auto-btn">AUTO</div>
```

```css
.categories-sidebar-popup-menu-row {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border-radius: 28px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    letter-spacing: -0.5px;
    color:#555B66;
}

.fashion-btn.active {
   background:#E53935;color:#fff!important;
}

.garden-btn.active {
  background:#D81B60;color:#fff!important;
}

.technology-btn.active {
  background:#8E24AA;color:#fff!important;
}

.auto-btn.active {
  background:#5E35B1;color:#fff!important;
}
```

```
$(".categories-sidebar-popup-menu-row" ).each(function (){
  $(this).click(function(){
    clearStyle();
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});

function clearStyle(){
  buttonWithActive = $('.categories-sidebar-popup-menu-row.active');
  buttonWithActive.removeClass('active');
}
```